# float precision problem :calculating of volume

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I wrote a code to calculate the volume of a cone
this is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<(float)1/3*3.1415926*2*2*5;
   return 0;
}
```

and I wrote another code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<(float)3.1415926*2*2*5*1/3;
    return 0;
}
```

the output of the first code is 20.944,while the second one is 20.9439,which is slightly different.
I think what both codes do is turn all numbers(1,3,2,5,3.1415926) into the type of float and calculate.
I don't know why the output is different.
Thank you for the reply.

I asked Chatgpt and it seems that it doesn't understand my question.

Comment: 1) Try using `double` for more precision / accuracy.  2) Use [`std::setprecision`](https://duckduckgo.com/?sites=cppreference.com&q=set+precision&ia=web) to *display* more precision.

Comment: In your favorite reference, review "integer division".

Comment: Keep in mind that `1.0f` is a float and `1.0` is a double so the two examples do differ. The order of the operations can also affect the outcome.  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) may get you started on your journey down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Floating point math is not associative and in the first case you are doing some of the calculations in `double` because thats the type of `3.1415926`, while in the second example you round it to `float` and then perform all operations in `float`.

Comment: I recommend using `double` for your calculations, and use `float` for storage of large data (unless the data needs to be higher precision).

Comment: Retired Ninja
Thanks for offering that link.It really helps.

Comment: user17732522 Thank you. I get the point.

Comment: @蔡天意, Curious, as pi is closer to 3.1415926535..., if only using 8 significant digits, why code 3.1415926 and not 3.1415927?  Further: for `double` constants best to use at least 17 digits: 3.1415926535897932.  For `float`, at least 9.